# Ionic Angular Js Factory services, factory have another factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mobile, ionic-framework

Sorry for beginner question , how to make the factory have another factory?I need the foods data have link to restaurant (like one to many relationship).

This is my code:

```
.factory('Foods', function() {
  var foods = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Food 1',
    price: '$12',
    category:'Appetizer',
    imageSrc: 'img/new_food1.jpg',
    restaurant:Restaurants.get(1),
  }];

  return {
    all: function() {
      return foods;
    },
    remove: function(food) {
      foods.splice(foods.indexOf(food), 1);
    },
    get: function(foodId) {
      for (var i = 0; i < foods.length; i++) {
        if (foods[i].id === parseInt(foodId)) {
          return foods[i];
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
  };
})
```

And this is my factory for restaurant code:

```
.factory('Restaurants', function() {
  var restaurants = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Restaurant 1',
    imageSrc: 'img/resto1.jpg'
  }];

  return {
    all: function() {
      return restaurants;
    },
    remove: function(restaurant) {
      restaurants.splice(restaurants.indexOf(restaurant), 1);
    },
    get: function(restaurantId) {
      for (var i = 0; i < restaurants.length; i++) {
        if (restaurants[i].id === parseInt(restaurantId)) {
          return restaurants[i];
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
  };
});
```

But it is makes the data error. How to make the array have object value (Restaurant)? Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Services can require other services. You can use the Angular auto injection by using a parameter with the name of your service :

```
.factory('Foods', function(Restaurants) {
    // ...
    Restaurants.get(42);
    // ...
});
```